# echo file_get_contents for ay url returns null in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am quite new to PHP. I am wondering why

```
    echo file_get_contents("https://www.google.com");
```

returns, actually for any URL, returns `null`  .

Also, `allow_url_fopen=on` in my php.ini. I addition, encoding the URL does not have any positive result (  `echo file_get_contents(urldecode("https://www.google.com/"));`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not showing NULL at my end.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with line of code you are using.

1. Make sure your system connected to internet, if its local system
2. Check php error logs
3. In php ini set **allow_url_fopen = On**

In alternative, try this method may be help you

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com");
  $file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $file_contents;
```

Answer (score 0):

A work around I found to use curl instead:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
```